# Remove an item from an array inside a local storage object with javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the `localStorage['cart']` and within it the array 'products'.
The retrieve data from `localStorage.getItem('cart')` looks like

```
{"products":
[
    {
    "id":"01",
    "name":"Product Name 01",
    "price":"Product Price 01",
    "image":"Product Imagem 01"
    },
    {
    "id":"02",
    "name":"Product Name 02",
    "price":"Product Price 02",
    "image":"Product Imagem 02"
    },
]}
```

I need, with an `onclick=` event, remove a specific item in `products` array, by using the `id`.

**EDIT**

```
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage["cart"]);
for (i=0; i < x; i++){
          if (json.products.[i].id == id){
            json.splice(i,1);
        }
      }
```

x are the json.products lenght.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try writing some code and come back to us when part of it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. We like a [mcve]

Comment: Which part exactly do you not know how to do? Turning the localstorage contents back to an object, finding the object by id, or removing the found object?

Comment: So read the string from local storage, convert it to an array, remove the item, convert it back to a string, reset the localstoarge.

Comment: I found something about that with the `splice` command, like my edit. But don't work...

Comment: What did you try that would not work show that code.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: `json.products.[i].id` is invalid syntax and should throw error. Any errors thrown in console?

Comment: charlietfl, yes, there's an error: ReferenceError: remove_cart is not defined

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with the function not being in the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea. Showing you how to parse the object from localStorage and 
how to write it back.

```js
(function() {
  //prime cache
  var obj = {
    "products": [{
      "id": "01",
      "name": "Product Name 01",
      "price": "Product Price 01",
      "image": "Product Imagem 01"
    }, {
      "id": "02",
      "name": "Product Name 02",
      "price": "Product Price 02",
      "image": "Product Imagem 02"
    }]
  };
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj));

}());

function removeItem(id) {
  var index = -1;
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || {}; //fetch cart from storage
  var items = obj.products || []; //get the products
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { //loop over the collection
    if (items[i].id === id) { //see if ids match
      items.splice(i, 1); //remove item from array
      break; //exit loop
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj)); //set item back into storage
}

console.log(localStorage.cart);
removeItem("01");
console.log(localStorage.cart);
```